# I know that map returns an iterator, but how can we assign an iterator to a and b?

Tags: python, iterator

What does the following code do?

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
```

I know that map returns an iterator, but how can we assign  an iterator to a and b? Is this like tuple assignment?

For understanding it, I did the following:

```
a, b = iter(range(1, 3))
print(a + b)
```

I know what happens, but I cannot fully understand how it works. Can someone explain it?

Comment: *"Is this like tuple assignment?"* - yes, exactly, Python will just try to iterate over whatever's in the right-hand side. [*"The object must be an iterable with the same number of items as there are targets in the target list..."*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements)

Comment: That's generator unpacking in action - the assignment exhausts the generator by assigning values to variables from left to right.

Comment: Also useful to know is that `a, b, *c = map(int, input().split())` will unpack the first two numbers to a and b and any remaining values to a list in c

Comment: @scotty3785 Great! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

the map is used to interact with all values and change it is value without writing a function it's known as an anonymous function here you take a,b which is equal to input and in python, you can define and take two values in python.
split is used to break the particular value.

```
 a = 'apple is good'
 print(a.split()) # ['apple','is','good']
```